# Dynamically Altering Relationship Criteria

Tags: orm, yii

Is there a way to dynamically modify the criteria given in Yii's relations model?

For example, I have this relationship in a Game model that will give me all of the points earned for it

```
'total_points' => [self::STAT, 'Point', 'game_id', 'select' => 'SUM(earned)']
```

This works just fine. However, I want to be able to pare this down based on a specific user ID chosen dynamically.

How would I create a method like the following that would return total_points earned in this game for a specific, changing user, where user_id is an attribute of the Point model?

```
function getUserPoints($user_id) {
    return $this->someCriteriaChangingMethod('user_id = $user_id')->total_points;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#dynamic-relational-query-options) this should work:

```
$model->total_points(array(
    'condition' => "user_id = :uId",
    'params' => array(':uId' => $user_id),
));
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Perfect. I swear I had tried this already, but I guess not. Maybe I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that. 
Here is an alternative method

```
function getUserPoints($user_id) {

     $row=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select("SUM(earned) as total_points")
                    ->from("point")
                    ->where('user_id = :user_id',array(":user_id"=>$user_id))
                    ->queryRow();
    return $row["total_points"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify a relationship dynamically, you can use the method [`CActiveRecord->getRelated()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#getRelated-detail), which allows me to do this

```
function getUserPoints($user_id) {
    $t = $this->getRelated('total_points', false, [
        'condition' => 'user_id = :user_id',
        'params' => [':user_id' => $user_id],
    ]);

    return $t;
}
```